# get a value in a config file regex grep

Tags: regex, grep

Using grep I can get a whole line from a config file,

```
grep <search-pattern> <file>
(eg. grep port config.txt )
```

but I need the result without the <search-pattern>, and also without any white-space.
(For instance, some people may pad the option with spaces or tabs.)

What is the best way to do this?

Finally this method is to be used in a perl script, so perhaps I could do,

```
$string =~ <whatever>;
```

and bypass having to execute a command with back-ticks ( `<command>` )

### Sample file:

```
# Replace DOMAINNAME with the "DOMAIN NAME" you want to create a Virtual Host for

server {
    server_name  www.DOMAINNAME;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://DOMAINNAME$1 permanent;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name DOMAINNAME;
                root   /var/www/DOMAINNAME/htdocs;
                index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/security;

# Logging --
access_log  /var/log/nginx/DOMAINNAME.access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/DOMAINNAME.error.log notice;

        # serve static files directly
        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$ {
            access_log        off;
            expires           max;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/DOMAINNAME.socket;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

---

I want to get the value of the listen port (80, in this case).

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: @user3247130 Why use grep in a Perl script? Perl's regex is much more powerful. If I understand your question right, you'll want something like `if ( $line =~ m/^\s*parameter\s*=\s*.*?\s*$/ ) $value = $1`. But then again, a proper configuration module (of the right flavour) would be even better.

Comment: Yeah, the config file is a file used in nginx. Ie. no equals, end-of-line is a semi-colon(;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just sed for this, no need to pipe from grep

```
sed -nr 's/^\s*listen\s+([0-9]+)\s*;$/\1/p' $nginxconfig
```

And you would put that into a variable thusly

```
myListeningPort="$(sed -nr 's/^\s*listen\s+([0-9]+)\s*.*;$/\1/p' $nginxconfig)"
```

Replace `$nginxconfig` with your config file or set the variable to your file location. This is versatile such that you can replace the directive key (`listen` in this case) with another that would contain a numeric value and it ignores leading spaces, invalid/incomplete lines (missing trailing ";"), and commented lines.

You can make it more generic by changing the capture group from just 0-9 to alphanumeric and other characters.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe it to sed:

```
grep port config.txt | sed 's/port\| \| ;//g'
```

The sed command means "substitute 'port' or ' ' or ';' with nothing", and "g" means "global" (all matches).

Comment: Great! And if I add [code]|sed 's/;//g'[/code] to the end it'll remove the semi-colon.  And now, how can I do this inside a perl script, and assign the outcome-value to a variable?

Comment: You can also remove semi colons in the one commend- see edited answer

Comment: The `grep` is adding no benefit. Just use seds `-n` arg with `p` to print the matching lines result.

Comment: @Ed Morton:Can you give an example, please?

Comment: Something like `sed -n 's/port\| \| ;//gp' config.txt` but untested since you didn't provide any sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

To get number `80` from the given sample you can do it with pure grep:

```
$ grep -Po '\blisten\s*\K[^;]*' file
80
```